# How to represent a floating point constant (such as 1e307) in SMT-LIB standard?

Tags: floating-point, constants, z3, smt

Currently I'm doing some experiments on Z3, and I have no idea to represent a floating point constant literal (such as 1e307) in SMT:

```
(declare-const a Real)
(assert (= a 1e+307))
(check-sat)
```

Same problem happened on FPA theory:

```
(declare-const a (_ FloatingPoint 11 53))
(assert (= a 1e+307))
(check-sat)
```

All those SMT code got error message saying:

```
(error "line 2 column 14: unknown constant e+307")
```

So any idea to represent decimal floating point constant in Z3 or SMT-LIB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the official syntax and semantics of the floating-point theory see [Theory FP](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml). The main constructor for FP numerals is

```
(fp (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec eb) (_ BitVec i) (_ FloatingPoint eb sb))
```

i.e., FP numbers are constructed from 3 bit-vectors. Further down in the document there are also conversion functions that can convert other numbers to floating point numbers (all called `to_fp`).

On top of those described there, Z3 also supports another conversion which looks like this:

```
((_ to_fp 11 53) RNE 1.0 307)
```

Note however, that the `307` here is a power of 2, not a power of 10, i.e., this is 1.0*(2^307) and some tools might print this as `1p307`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful answer!